# Fit curve with rectangles

Tags: optimization, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have a one-dimensional set of points, i.e. $(n,y_n), 1\leq n \leq N$. I want to fit them with a linear combination of $k$ [rectangular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function) in a least-squared-error sense. Each rectangle is parametrised by a left edge, right edge, and height. It is similar to the [Lebesgue sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) but I am looking at horizontal strips of flexible width and height to achieve minimum error.

It seems to be a really straightforward and very linear problem, but I don't see this facility in MATLAB curve fitting toolbox, and the internet is not helping at all.

I am sure (I think) I can formulate the equations and write the code, it might take me a couple of hours. But should I do it? Is there some reason it's not widely used? Is it actually ill-defined (in the sense there is no optimum)?

Comment: What do you mean by a 1D set of points? A dotted or discrete curve?

Comment: Discrete set of points. X-axis is just natural numbers 1 to N.

Comment: So you have a set of coordinates $(n, Y_n)$, $1\le n \le N$. What do you mean by "fit" ? Have each point in  at least one rectangle? Are you somehow paving your discrete curve with rectangles?

Comment: @LaurentDuval Thanks for the help, question edited for clarity.

Comment: It looks clearer now. Yet, are you looking at [Lebesque like integration](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uh2M3.png)? The "fit" is still not clear to me

Comment: @LaurentDuval Yes almost exactly! Except that I want to fit a finite number of strips, with each its own left-edge, right-edge, and height.

Comment: This problem isn't actually linear. You could represent your fit as: $f(n) = \sum_j^m h_j rect(n, n_l^{(j)},n_r^{(j)})$. This fit shows nonlinearity in the unknown variables, the desired heights, $h_j$, and the desired bounds for each rectangle, $n_l^{(j)}, n_r^{(j)}$

Comment: You still haven't said so explicitly, but I presume that you are trying to approximate your set of points using a *sum* of $k$ rectangular functions.  Is that right?  And are these $k$ functions allowed to overlap (that is, can there be any x position for which more than one of them has nonzero value), or must they all be disjoint?  In the latter case, I'm pretty sure this can be solved in $O(n^2)$ time with dynamic programming; I'll post a solution if you clarify.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Well I did say "linear combination", but yes I meant sum. Regarding overlap, I'm not sure... I don't know how to precisely frame the problem ; if I did, I would have added it to the question. Intuitively I am guessing each rectangle would have an associated level, and rectangles at the same level cannot overlap, but those of a different level can. Each level encompasses more of the x-axis than its next higher level. Just what floated into my mind.

Comment: @choward But each rectangle is linear in height : your formula shows it by multiplying by $h_j$ outside the $rect$ function. The optimization problem is not linear though, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Sure the problem is linear in height, but it's nonlinear in the things you are solving for(since you want more than just height if I understood correctly). So yes, I meant the optimization problem is nonlinear.

Comment: From the diagram that Laurent Duval showed, it seems that the rectangles *can* overlap, but when they do, they *must* be nested.  Is that right?  Or is it possible to e.g. have 1 function that is 1 in the x range 5-7, and 0 elsewhere, and another function that is 1 in the x range 6-8?  If non-nested are allowed, it gets more complicated.

Comment: @j_random_hacker My real intention is to have something like an [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) , where the first set of rectangles gets as close as possible to the data, the next set of rectangles gets as close as possible to the resulting error in the data, and so on. For some as yet unknown definition of "as close as possible" to the data. To answer your question, non-nested rectangles probably shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Well, for the time being I've given a solution to a problem that is at least related to what you want to do -- please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

- the rectangles do not overlap at all on the $x$ axis, and that
- the sum of the rectangles should never exceed the value of the original function at any point,

the following simple dynamic programming algorithm will calculate the optimal set of at most $k$ rectangles w.r.t. least squared error in $O(n^2k)$ time and $O(nk)$ space in the worst case.  Although this might seem prohibitive for large $n$, there are some refinements that mean that many inputs will take much less time -- and if necessary, some shortcuts that improve the runtime at the cost of sacrificing optimality.

Define $f(i, j)$ to be the least error that can be achieved on the subsequence $1, \dots, i$ ($i \le n$) using at most $j \le k$ rectangles.  To avoid confusion about which data points are supported by which rectangles, assume all rectangles begin and end at positions having fractional part 0.5.  Also define $g(i, j)$ to be the least error that can be achieved for the subsequence $i, ..., j$ using a single rectangle that ends at $x$ co-ord $j + 0.5$ and begins at any position $\ge i + 0.5$ and $\le j - 0.5$ and having fractional part 0.5.  Finally, let $adjErr(i, j, h)$ be the sum of squared residuals over the range $i, ..., j$ under the assumption that a single rectangle of height $h$ spans this region.  Then:

$f(i, j) = \min_{0 \le m < j}{(f(m, j-1) + g(m+1, i))}$

$g(i, j) = \min_{i \le m < j}{(adjErr(i, m, 0) + adjErr(m+1, j, min_{m<r\le j}x_r))}$

$adjErr(i, j, h) = \sum_{m=i}^j(x_m - h)^2$

The overall lowest possible error is given by $f(n, k)$.  An actual solution (i.e. a set of rectangles) having this best-possible error level can be found by tracing back through the DP matrix, looking for the $m$ value that allowed $f(i, j)$ to take its minimum value.

If this is useful, comment and I'll come back to flesh out the details a bit more.

Comment: That looks great! I came as far as $adjErr()$, but then only thought of brute-forcing it instead of DP, which is what I'm trying to understand now. Will update.

Comment: Glad to hear it :)  Don't have much time right now, but I'm now wondering whether computing $adjErr()$ causes the time complexity to exceed $O(n^2k)$...  Anyway, if you're prepared to (or would prefer to!) use rectangles that can be higher than some input points, then the optimal height $h$ to use with $adjErr()$ is just the mean of all samples in the range $i, ..., j$, and $adjErr(i, j)$ is then just the variance times $j - i + 1$, which can be computed efficiently online.

Comment: I had assumed exactly that (rectangle height can be greater than input values), and got exactly what you mentioned :). I have a feeling though that keeping heights strictly lesser than input values is more realistic. But with more than one rectangle, the local optimum is no longer an optimum. Have to verify though, after understanding your DP.

Comment: I'm sure the formulation in my answer is correct for the always-stay-at-or-below-the-data-points version of the problem (unless I made an off-by-one error with the indices, as I often do...), but it's probably slower to compute.  We don't have any "local" optima to worry about: every possible solution to a given subproblem $(i, j)$ either has a rightmost rectangle ending at $x = i + 0.5$, or its rightmost rectangle ends at some $i' + 0.5 < i + 0.5$ (imagine an empty solution has a rectange ending at -0.5). ...

Comment: ...  In the latter case, the best possible solution is given by $f(i', j)$.  In the former case, we try all possible rectangles ending at $i + 0.5$ and combine each of them with the best overall solution that ends anywhere to the left of that particular rectangle and uses $\le j-1$ rectangles.  We don't need to try combining a rightmost rectangle with *all possible* such leftward sub-solutions because the two parts (rightmost rectangle, and leftward sub-solution) don't overlap, so their costs are simply summed.

Comment: (We're trying to find a rightmost rectangle $r$ and a left-of-$r$ sub-solution that minimises $cost(r) + cost(s)$, and I'm saying that it's enough to try all possible $r$ and just pick the one minimising $cost(r) + cost(s^*)$, where $s^*$ is an *optimal* left-of-$r$ solution.  Suppose to the contrary that for some rightmost rectangle $r$ there exists a left-of-$r$ sub-solution $s$ such that $cost(r) + cost(s) < cost(r) + cost(s^*)$: But this implies $cost(s) < cost(s^*)$, which obviously contradicts the definition of $s^*$, so it can't happen.)